# How To Handle Wildcards in Snakemake

Tags: python, bash, wildcard, snakemake

Let's assume I have a snakemake rule like this:

```
rule test:
input: "{mywildcard}"
output: "{mywildcard}.txt"
shell: "some command {input} > {output}"
```

In order to get the output file, I would like to remove the last extension inside my {mywildcard} first which might look like this "A.tar".

My output should be "A.txt". How can I do this with a dynamic approach in Snakemake without modifying my wildcard in the input directive?

I thought about using

```
output: os.path.splitext("{mywildcard}")[0] + ".txt"
```

But this approach does not work with the Snakemake wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snakemake works from output to input files.  It can be a little confusing at first, but you *request* outputs and snakemake determines what inputs it needs.  In your case, I think you want the extension of the input to also be used in the rule?

```
rule test:
    input: "{mywildcard}.tar"
    output: "{mywildcard}.txt"
    shell: "some command {input} > {output}"
```

That will work, if you need the value of `{mywildcard}.tar` you can reference it with `{input}` in your shell command.  If you have a more exotic use case please update your question.

Comment: Hi, I actually don't want to include the extension of the input in the output. I mean what you potentially could do is also introducing two wildcards (one for the file name and one for the extension) and then select the former one for generating the output.